# Force ggplot2 to show legends (barchar and geom_line)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, line, legend

Easy question: I'm creating a barchart in ggplot2 with both a stacked barchart and a geom_line referring to different parts of the same dataset.

No matter what I do, I'm unable to show the legends (one for the stacked barchart and another one for the geom_line), but I need these as neither of the axis should be labelled.

What do I do?

This is my dataset:

```
> dput(par_brood_2020)
structure(list(`Prevalence-host.age.relationship` = c("<7 days", 
"7-10 days", "10-12 days", "12-15 days", "15-20 days", "20-25 days"
), Broods = c(6, 6, 3, 2, 4, 1), Parasites = c(92, 66, 32, 9, 
27, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is my code:

```
ggplot(par_nest_2020, aes(x=par_nest_2020$"Prevalence- 
host.age.relationship",y=par_nest_2020$"Nestlings")) + geom_col() +
geom_bar(fill="#808080", stat="identity") +
xlab(" ") + ylab(" ") +
ggtitle("2020 - HOST-AGE RELATIONSHIP") +
scale_fill_manual(name=" ",values="#808080") +
theme_classic() +
theme(legend.key.size = unit (10, "pt")) +  
theme(axis.line.x = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid'),
      axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid')) +
theme(title = element_text(face="plain", size = 12)) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust =2)) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1)) +
theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
geom_line(data=par_nest_2020,aes(x =par_nest_2020$"Prevalence-host.age.relationship", y 
=par_nest_2020$"Parasites"), group = 1, col = "#E60000", show.legend=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a legend you have to map on aesthetics, i.e. you have to map on `color` and `fill` inside `aes()`. In your case you could simply use some constant values like e.g. `color="Broods"` which will then automatically show up as labels. Additionally, as a general rule when using `ggplot2` don't use `par_nest_2020$...` to map on aesthetics. Simply use the column names.

```r
library(ggplot2)

par_brood_2020 <- structure(list(
  `Prevalence-host.age.relationship` = c("<7 days", "7-10 days", "10-12 days", "12-15 days", "15-20 days", "20-25 days"),
  Broods = c(6, 6, 3, 2, 4, 1), Parasites = c(92, 66, 32, 9, 27, 5)
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

par_brood_2020$`Prevalence-host.age.relationship` <- factor(par_brood_2020$`Prevalence-host.age.relationship`, c("<7 days", "7-10 days", "10-12 days", "12-15 days", "15-20 days", "20-25 days"))

ggplot(par_brood_2020, aes(x = `Prevalence-host.age.relationship`, y = Broods)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = "Broods")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Parasites, color = "Parasites"), group = 1) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, title = "2020 - HOST-AGE RELATIONSHIP", color = NULL, fill = NULL) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "#808080") +
  scale_color_manual(values = "#E60000") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(10, "pt")) +
  theme(
    axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
    axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid")
  ) +
  theme(title = element_text(face = "plain", size = 12)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 2)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
#> Warning: The `size` argument of `element_line()` is deprecated as of ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `linewidth` argument instead.
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I know I should avoid using the $ formatting, but I was having trouble with the chart without it, don't know why...